# How to properly specify an input shape for a LSTM model in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Let's say we have a **Numpy** array, that contains integers.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

And we have a Keras model.

```
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(arr)))
```

How does one properly specify an input shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input data to an LSTM layer needs to be three-dimensional and in the shape `(num_samples, timesteps, num_features)`.

The `input_shape` you specify to an LSTM layer is in the shape `(timesteps, num_features)`. `input_shape` doesn't care about the number of samples, just about the per-sample shape.

If we assume `timesteps=1`, you'd want to do something like this.

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr.shape  # (3,)
arr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], 1, 1)
arr.shape  # (3, 1, 1)

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2])))
```

It doesn't make a ton of sense to use LSTMs with `timesteps=1`, but hopefully you get the idea.